# ClassNotFoundException extending Android MultiDexApplication class

Tags: android, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception, android-multidex

I'm spending hours to solve this problem, but can't find a solution between the dozens of replies for similar problems.

So there's my problem. I'm creating a simple multidex Android app and I need to execute some things at app startup. So, I've extended the MultiDexApplication class, added the class path to application element on AndroidManifest.xml file but crashes every time I run it with the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application rmpt.app.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "rmpt.app.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/rmpt.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/rmpt.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4472)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:744)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "rmpt.app.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/rmpt.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/rmpt.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4472) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

If I remove the android:name attribute from the AndroidManifest.xml file (so it uses the default android Application class) everything works fine, but I **NEED** to execute some things at onCreate method of my application.

I leave here my files so you can see them and maybe see something wrong (already 2 days trying to solve this problem for me)

---

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="rmpt.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".MyApplication">

        <activity android:name=".view.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

*MyApplication.java*

```
package rmpt.app;

import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // do my stuff
    }
}
```

---

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rmpt.app"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

}
```

I'm working on MacOS 10.11.6

Comment: no, where do I put this?

Comment: @rmpt Did you solved this problem? If not: I'll suggest (as a first step) to verify that your `MyApplication` class is included in classes.dex. You can do that directly from Android Studio using ApkAnalyzer.

Comment: @Alex I'm using IntelliJ with Android Support and not Android Studio. There's any way to use ApkAnalyzer in it? I realy don't understand, I have a similar setup on another project and works great, in this one I have this problem.

Comment: You can use ClassyShark instead of ApkAnalyzer.

Comment: I've run ClassyShark and I can see my classes on classes3.dex and not in classes.dex. Is this a problem? If so, how to solve it?

Comment: Just to verify, `rmpt.app.MyApplication` class gets packaged to classes3.dex?

Comment: Yes, exactly! inside classes folder I have classes.dex, classes2.dex and classes3.dex. rmpt.app.MyApplication is inside classes3.dex

Comment: Interesting. It appears that you're using Jack (which have [known problems](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37121578) with legacy Multidex compatibility) - can you try to disable it (temporarily comment all your Java-8 stuff)?

Comment: Cannot do that, I'm using external libs depending on java 8. Do you know if I update my tablet to Android 5.1 and target my app to a higher version (API 22) this problem will remain?

Comment: If you want to target API levels prior to 21, you'll have to use the legacy multidex library. Otherwise, set 21 as minSdkVersion and don't use it (since the platform has built-in support starting from this version).

Comment: I was using minSdkVersion 18 due to my development environment (ASUS MeMO Pad ME302C), but seems that I have to buy a more recent one and target the app to min 21. I'm stuck here for weeks and cannot waste more time. ME302C is a little deprecated anyway...

Comment: @AlexLipov Worked for me. I removed multidex from project, minsdk 21.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions [at this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep). They fix the error you have encountered.

According to [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.html)

> the primary classes.dex must contain the classes necessary for calling
>   this class methods.

ie, MyApplication must be a part of classes.dex as it calls the MultiDex#install(Context) method. The instructions in the aforementioned link help you decide which classes must be included in the primary dex file (classes.dex)